# Как убрать подчеркивание у ссылки?

Tags: css

Здравствуйте. Навешал такие обработчики:

```
a{
color: #8d8176;
text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover{
color: #8d8176;
text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited{
color: #8d8176;
text-decoration: none;
}
a:active{
text-decoration: none;
}
```

но подчеркивание всеравно есть при нажатии.

Comment: Без кода трудно сказать. Может класс добавляется, может приоритет выше/ниже. Попробуйте еще a:focus {text-decoration: none;}

Comment: В вашем примере подчеркивания у ссылки нет. И достаточно всего одного text-decoration:none для дефолтного положения ссылки. Проверяйте какие классы еще навешаны на ссылки. Может там вообще border-bottom установлен...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Значит для ваших ссылок как-то был указан другой стиль. Попробуйте поместить код в конец и добавить `!important`. а для всех псевдоэлементов указывать нет смысла т.к. `color` и `text-decoraition` наследуется. а еще может и `border` установлен.

```css
a{
color: #8d8176;
text-decoration: none !important;
border: none !important;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://google.com/search">Google.com</a>
```

Comment: спасибо сработало